# Need help proving the sequence $(T^n x)$ is Cauchy for any $x \in X$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

(X, d) is complete. $T$ has the following property: given any $0 < a < b$, there exists $0 \le \alpha(a, b) < 1$ such that $d(Tx, Ty) \le \alpha(a, b) d(x,y)$ whenever $a < d(x,y)<b$.

We've proven in class that $a_n=d(T^{n}x, T^{n+1}x)$ converges to $0$.

What I've tried so far is that:

> Given $\epsilon_1 >0$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   for all $n \ge N$, $$d(T^nx, T^{n+1}x) < \epsilon_1.$$
>
> Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $n > m \ge N$, we can fix $\epsilon_1
> =\epsilon/(n-m)$, so that $$d(T^n x, T^m x) < (n-m) \epsilon_1 = \epsilon,$$

using the triangle inequality. Is this right?

Edit: I've thought about this some more, and have come up with a possible alternate proof:

We can use the given property to construct a sequence:

$d(T^k x, T^{k+1}) \le \alpha(a_1, b_1) \cdots \alpha(a_k, b_k) d(x, Tx)$

Taking $m = max\{\alpha(a_1, b_1), \cdots, \alpha(a_k, b_k)\}$, we get

$d(T^k x, T^{k+1}) \le m^k d(x, Tx)$

Then $m^k < 1$ for all $k > 1$ so that $\sum_{k \ge 1} d(T^kx, T^{k+1}) < \infty$. The partial sums of the series is then Cauchy and we obtain $|S_n - S_m| = |\sum_{k=m}^{n}d(T^kx, T^{k+1}x)| < \epsilon$ for $n > m \ge N$.

This means $d(T^{n}x, T^{m}) \le \sum_{k=m}^{n}d(T^kx, T^{k+1}x) < \epsilon.$ Done?

Comment: It is not, since $\epsilon_1$ depends on $n,m$.

Comment: @Crostul: I don't know of any others ways to go about proving this. Will you please help? I've spent all day thinking about this, and all I've come up with is the flawed proof above.

Comment: @Crostul: I've edited my post and added a different proof. Can you check, please?

Comment: Again, this proof is not correct.